# How to add additional worksheets to an Excel from DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I'm trying to create an excel report that has multiple sheets.  each of these sheets has data that comes from a DataTable that results from a SQL query.  The inital worksheet is created correctly, however, i'm unable to create the second worksheet.  I understand what i'm doing wrong, but i'm just not sure how to add a worksheet using the below code without creating a new excel workbook everything.

I was thinking about just creating the workbook and then just adding sheets.  But I cant seem to make it all click.

This is what i'm trying:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Excel_FromDataTable(testingTable);
        Excel_FromDataTable(testingTable);
    }
}

private static void Excel_FromDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
    var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(true);

    int iCol = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        iCol++;
        excel.Cells[1, iCol] = c.ColumnName;
    }

    int iRow = 0;
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        iRow++;
        // add each row's cell data...
        iCol = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            iCol++;
            excel.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol] = r[c.ColumnName];
        }
    }
    // Global missing reference for objects we are not defining...
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    // If wanting to Save the workbook...
    workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\MyExcelWorkBook2.xlsx");
    workbook.Close();
}
```

Comment: I think you had a copy-and-paste error in Main.  This line:  `Excel_FromDataTable(testingTable)` is shown twice, and on the following line, you have an unmatched closing brace.  I considered editing it myself, but I thought better of it since I don't know your exact intent.

Comment: @David no i'm simply wanted to create the same data twice on two sheets as a test

Comment: Ok - but regardless, that unmatched brace in Main is not going to fly :)

Comment: @David it's because i took code out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this

```
Static void Main()
{

    var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(true);

    AddExcelSheet(dt1, workbook);
    AddExcelSheet(dt2, workbook);

    workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\MyExcelWorkBook2.xlsx");
    workbook.Close();

}

private static void AddExcelSheet(DataTable dt, Workbook wb)
{    
    Excel.Sheets sheets = wb.Sheets;
    Excel.Worksheet newSheet = sheets.Add();
    int iCol = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        iCol++;
        newSheet.Cells[1, iCol] = c.ColumnName;
    }

    int iRow = 0;
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        iRow++;
        // add each row's cell data...
        iCol = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            iCol++;
            newSheet.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol] = r[c.ColumnName];
        }
}
```

Comment: User - you're going to have to show me a little bit better example, sorry.

Comment: Hi @user, shouldn't Workbook wb be passed by reference?

Comment: @joseph4tw An object need not be passed by reference if it is being merely operated upon, as in this case, if I am changing the object and expect the change to be retained by the caller, then yes the object needs to be passed by reference

Comment: @user1556110, my bad.  I forgot that passing a class object by value merely copies only a reference to the same object, not the entire object itself.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @user1556110 Question for you, how come the sheets are being placed in reverse order of what i'm passing in.  Meaning the first DataTable is the last sheet?

Comment: @Mike Check the method on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.add(v=office.11).aspx. If Before and After are both omitted, the new sheet is inserted before the active sheet.