# Export dataset to the excel sheet in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I tried to export the dataset which have 4 tables to the excel sheet, Unfortunately I can't. I have code to export data table to excel. So instead of dataset, I called the "ExportToExcel" function which I have in my code to export datatable to excel 4 times. But once it created the first sheet, it stops the control flow. Control doesn't call the second function ("ExportToExcel(dsResult.Tables[2], "AthleteSentCount");") Here is the code

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ExportToExcel(dsResult.Tables[3], "AthleteInboxCount");
     ExportToExcel(dsResult.Tables[2], "AthleteSentCount");
     ExportToExcel(dsResult.Tables[0], "CoachInboxCount");
     ExportToExcel(dsResult.Tables[1], "CoachSentCount");
}

void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt, string FileName)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string filename = FileName + ".xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
        dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
        dgGrid.DataBind();

        //Get the HTML for the control.
        dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
        //Write the HTML back to the browser.
        //Response.ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                              "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        Response.Write(tw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

If any body knows to export the dataset to the excel with the bar chart please help me. Else please give your solution to the problem.

Comment: what issue u r getting in this?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Control stops its operation once it creates its first excel sheet ie once the "ExportToExcel(dsResult.Tables[3], "AthleteInboxCount");" function got excecuted

Comment: ys why not?try to pass datatabe in a loop till Data Set length

Comment: I tried, but it stops the flow after "Response.End();" method while executing the first loop

Comment: remove Response.End(). it will work

Comment: yeah, i already tried. If so "Corrupted Content Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected." error will occur on browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your function start streaming content

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
```

to end user and END it with

```
Response.End();
```

Moreover if you fix this your code will product 4 excel files.

There is an existing code for creating Excel sheets on stack overflow: [How to add additional worksheets to an Excel from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980640/how-to-add-additional-worksheets-to-an-excel-from-datatable)
The only change you will have to made will be saving xlsx to stream and transmit this stream to user.

Comment: Thank you @Garath, your post is very useful to me. I have to made some little changes like syntax. But it works great. Again thanks.

Comment: Can I know why the control stops when it creates the first sheet in the above code?

Comment: @ArunKumarT the code not excatly stops, but because you call `Response.End();` the rest of code is not send to end user.

Answer (score 1):

Written in WCF & ASMX

---

But I used EPPuls. dlll file its Open Source dll. Please check below link for Reference. http://epplus.codeplex.com/.

Code :

```
string excelFileName = @"E:\GOPI_16122016.xls";
 DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
 string worksheetsName = "Report";
 ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage();
 ExcelWorksheet wrkSht = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetsName);
 wrkSht.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
 pack.SaveAs(new FileInfo(excelFileName));
  MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("gopi@kanike.com", "GOPIKRISHNA"));

                msg.From = new MailAddress("No-reply@domain.co.in", "Domain");
                msg.Subject = "REPORTS";
                string str = "Dear Team,<br/> Please find the Reports Details <br/><br/>";
                Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(excelFileName);
                msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                msg.Body = str ;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("No-reply@domain.co.in", "");
                client.Port = 25; // You can use Port 25 if 587 is blocked (mine is!)
                client.Host = "domain@.com";
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: If you could elaborate a bit more on your answer, clean up the code, and adapt it a bit to the specific case of downloading an excel file rather than e-mail it (i.e. the `Response` part), I think you would not only help the OP but also many other people. EPPlus is SO much powerful and simple than many other alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to download and use my free C# library to export a DataSet to a "real" Excel .xlsx file.

It uses the Microsoft OpenXML libraries, and takes just one line of code.

[Export to Excel](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)

It looks like your code is for an ASP.Net web application, so using my library, your code would just look like this:

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(dsResult, "YourExcelfilename.xlsx", Response);
}
```

Just one line of code, and you'll get a real Excel file written to your page's *Response*.

It will contain one Worksheet per DataTable in your DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some souce code sample about how to [export dataset to Excel](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-dataset-to-excel.html). You can use ExcelWorksheet.easy_insertDataSet method to insert multiple datatables.

About the other question, check this code for [bar chart](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/html/programmerGuide/basics/chartTypes.html) and adjust the code to generate bar chart like this:

```
xlsChart.easy_setChartType(Chart.CHART_TYPE_BAR_CLUSTERED);
```